Freezing ubuntu 22.04.4
I am having trouble with ubuntu 22.04.4 freezing all the time.  I tried to install a driver for nvidia video card, it downloaded OK but will not install, here is the following errors.
rod@rod:~/Downloads$ ls -la
total 165008
drwxr-xr-x  2 rod rod      4096 Apr 18 13:57 .
drwxr-x--- 18 rod rod      4096 Apr 15 18:57 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 rod rod 168953614 Apr 18 13:57 NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.28.run
rod@rod:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.28.run
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.28.run
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.28.run'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.28.run'


Does this answer your question? How do I install .run files?

Non-reproducible problem: "This caused me a great headache so I went back to 18.04 lts and everything looked good."

I would strongly recommend either installing it from the official repos:
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-###

or at worst one of the PPAs like https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
I've heard horror stories of using the website download. Haven't done that personally in a long, long time.

The Nvidia driver installer has nothing to do with apt package manager.So what you need to do is to run it directly:
chmod +x ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.28.run
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-455.28.run


Seems that you are new to ubuntu, check this post to learn about how to install nvidia drivers with *.run files.

@mpboden I have edited the answer and I did not mean to disrespect anyone, thank you!

sorry for such a long delay, I tried all the suggestions here but nothing good happened, unfortunately.
I finally bit the bullet and reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04, nothing good happened by doing that either, all I got was a screen that seemed divided, it used the top left quarter only which shuddered every-time I moved the mouse.  This caused me a great headache so I went back to 18.04lts  and everything looked good.  So I used that until I get back from a nervous breakdown, calm to a murderous rage, put away the axe, then unlock the computer.  Thank you all for your help, much appreciated.
